# trouble in sending a string to database using intents

Tags: android

I can't send a string to database via intents  . 
I tried to do this

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql =     "create table "+ DATABASE_TABLE + " ( "
                + KEY_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , "
                + NOTE + "  text  ) " ;

        db.execSQL(sql);

         String x=getIntent().getExtras().getString("message");

         sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + NOTE+ " ) "
                + " values ( x)";
        db.execSQL(sql);

    }
```

but it keeps telling me that "getIntent()" can't be resolved and i imported intent class already 
does anybody know how to pass a string to a database using intents ? 
thanks in advance .

Comment: There's a really nice section on saving data in databases in the developer docs that you should really check out bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getIntent()` method is defined in `Activity`, not in `SQLiteOpenHelper`. `SQLiteOpenHelper` has a `getWritableDatabase()` method which you can use to get a reference to your database.

For example, you can set up your database when your Activity launches, get a reference to the database using `getWritableDatabase()`, and then write to it using data from your intent.

Comment: thanks for your help , but could you show me this in code please ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are trying to insert an entry to the database. Then I would not understand why you want to use an intent? Can you make some clarification on what you are trying to do with it?

The easiest way to insert an entry to the database would be create a method name insert(String message) in SQLiteOpenHelper something along this line:

```
public long insert(String message) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME,message);
    return db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
```

Comment: i have a textField in an activity and I wanna store it in database (which is in another activity ) so we should send strings between activities using intents . that's why i used intent .

Comment: It would be better idea if you have separate class for database storage. Something like:
    public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        // Your database code here    
    }
Then, in activity, you can call the DatabaseHelper method to insert(String message) as above.
Please prefer to MVC model for additional information.